# Javascript not replacing or modifying original instance

Tags: javascript

My code works when using alert();

It shows the string properly formatted. However, when I remove the alert() it does not modify the original string.

The basic overview is I need to modify a string to remove a word with brackets. The original code would be:

```
<span id="frame_1">
                This is a Test [TEST]
            </span>

<span id="frame_2">
                This is a Test [THIS]
            </span>
```

My basic goals are:

Identify all widget containers that contain one of the following strings in their title and store them each in a variable:
[TEST]
[THIS]

Strip the bracketed substrings from the widget title
Example - If the title is This is a Test [TEST], manipulate the element to make the title This is a Test.

and my JS,

```
var testElements = [];
var thisElements = [];
spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
var span = spans[i];
 if(spans[i].innerHTML.indexOf('[THIS]') != -1) {
    thisElements.push(span.innerHTML.replace(/ \[[\s\S]*?\]/g, '')); }


    else if(spans[i].innerHTML.indexOf('[TEST]') != -1) {
    testElements.push(span.innerHTML.replace(/ \[[\s\S]*?\]/g, '')); }
}
```

***** Updated Code *****

The dilemma now is as follows:

Hide all of the test widgets by default. The widget being:

```
<div id="jive-widgetframe_5243545"
```

Add an event listener to show all TEST widgets and hide all THIS widgets when someone clicks the TEST button at the top of the page.

The button is a data-target:

```
<div class="ac-category" data-target="TESTWidgets">
```

Add an event listener to show all THIS widgets and hide all TEST widgets when someone clicks the THIS button at the top of the page.

The button is a data-target:

```
<div class="ac-category" data-target="THISWidgets">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace `innerHTML` this way, you always have to set new text with `innerHTML =`. The simple fix is to change those lines to:

```
span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/ \[[\s\S]*?\]/g, '');
thisElements.push(span);
```

Also if there's only plain text inside the `<span>`s you should consider using `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` since the latter causes a layout pass from the browser.

**Edit:**
Here's how you can add a button to show/hide them. You can create a class for them in CSS which adds `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;` and add an event listener to a button to toggle this class.

```js
var testButton = document.querySelector('[data-target="TESTWidgets"]');
var thisButton = document.querySelector('[data-target="THISWidgets"]');
var testElements = [];
var thisElements = [];
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
  var span = spans[i];

  if (span.innerHTML.indexOf('[THIS]') != -1) {
    span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/ \[[\s\S]*?\]/g, '');
    thisElements.push(span);
  } else if(spans[i].innerHTML.indexOf('[TEST]') != -1) {
    span.classList.add('hidden');
    span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/ \[[\s\S]*?\]/g, '');
    testElements.push(span);
  }
}

testButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (var i = 0, l = testElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    testElements[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = thisElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    thisElements[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
});

thisButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (var i = 0, l = thisElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    thisElements[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = testElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    testElements[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="ac-category" data-target="TESTWidgets">Show TEST Elements (Hide THIS)</div>
<div class="ac-category" data-target="THISWidgets">Show THIS Elements (Hide TEST)</div>
<br/>
<span id="frame_1">This is a Test [TEST]</span>
<span id="frame_2">This is a Test [THIS]</span>
<span id="frame_3">This is a Test [TEST]</span>
<span id="frame_4">This is a Test [THIS]</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! My follow up would be if it would be possible to hide every <span>instance for thisElement by default? Then later add an eventListener to show and hide both testElement and thisElement depending on which widget is clicked?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my answer. Create a class to hide them in CSS. When you are collecting the elements initially, you can add this class to them. I'm not sure exactly the interaction you want with clicking on particular elements, so I just added a button with an event listener that toggles the class. You could modify this to work on the elements you want to listen for the clicks.

Comment: Note the difference between `display:none` and `visiblity:hidden` is that display will completely remove the element from the DOM including its position in the content layout, while visibility will preserve the element's place in the content but just makes it invisible.

Comment: What would you recommend if the button you need to click is a data-target and not a button?

Comment: Can you elaborate more or edit your question to include the relevant code?

Comment: Sure! I will edit the code to reflect where I am stuck at

Comment: I updated my answer... you can use `querySelector()` to get an element by its data-attribute, and I made the event handlers show & hide the correct type of elements.